# Mysql select from table by comparing value in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables first and second.

first Table:

```
ID NAME     ADDRESS
1  test     testing address
2  test1    testing address 
3  test2    testing address
4  test3    testing address
```

second Table:

```
T_ID      Partner_id      date
  1          2          12345678
  3          4          32164584
```

If input T_id is given. Then corresponding Partner_id is taken and it is compared with the ID from first table and corresponding row should be selected.
Can you please tell me. 
In php I can write this with two queries but I want it to be in a single query.

Queries in php:

```
$q=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Partner_id from second where T_ID=1");
$qa=mysqli_fetch_array($q);  
$w=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from first where ID=$qa[0]");
```

But, how to combine this two statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specified result can be returned using a query with a *join* operation.

```
SELECT f.*
  FROM first f
  JOIN second s
    ON s.Partner_id = f.ID
 WHERE s.T_ID=1
```

Note that there is a potential for this to return more rows that the original, if the first query returns more than one row. (That is, we don't assume that `T_ID` is unique in `second`, or that every row with a given `T_ID` value will have identical values for `Partner_id`.)

There are other query patterns that will return an equivalent result, but the *join* operation is the normative pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT * FROM first WHERE ID IN( SELECT Parent_id FROM second WHERE T_ID = 1 )

     or 

    SELECT * FROM first WHERE ID = ( SELECT Parent_id FROM second WHERE T_ID = 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use union ,see this [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp/%22this%20Link%22)

where The SQL UNION operator combines the result of two or more SELECT statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FORM first_table AS f
JOIN second_table AS s
ON s.parent_id =f.id
WHERE s.T_ID = $id
```